Detect Largest connected component in a scatter plot (on bivariate data)
I have bivariate data representing the position of an identified reference point along a y axis which ranges from -100 to 100 mm. When I plot this data in a scatter plot I can see outliers and groups of wrongfully identified reference points. I know that since it is a spatial use case a continous track of points must exist along the x axis without large jumps in y. So using a computer vision algorithm I can identify a largest connected component with a very wide (large x component) and short (small y component) kernel using some erosion beforehand. However I dont know how to extract the information from the computer vision approach such that I can use it in my original data which is in x and y representing milimiters. The other alternative I am thinking about is using some sort of clustering or other type of (path) finding algorithm which could identify for me what the largest connected component horizontally wise is.

General Ideas are much appreciated.
I tried a largest connected component algorithm from opencv and some DBSCAN / OPTICS approaches. I expect a output which tells me which points are outliers, considering that outliers might even be denser point clouds based on the notion of one connected component going from start to end of my scatter plot. Thus I can remove these points from my bivariate data.
EDIT:
HDBSCAN results:


Could you share the data as code or a file (csv / mat / npz)?

I tried HDBSCAN on a similar type of problem and the separation looks good to me:

Using defaults, the algorithm separates the largest mass  from the more sporadic outliers. Some points are assigned to smaller clusters, but the algorithm does well at capturing the main mass.

Reproducible example
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#
# Synthesise data for testing
#
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)

N = 1000
x = np.linspace(0, 6 * np.pi, num=N)
y = np.sin(x) / 2 + rng.randn(N) / 4
y[::5] = rng.randn(N//5) / 2 + 1


#
# Cluster using HDBSCAN
#
from sklearn.cluster import HDBSCAN
clusterer = HDBSCAN().fit(np.column_stack([x, y]))

#Memeberships per cluster
cluster_ids = np.unique(clusterer.labels_)
membership_counts = [np.sum(clusterer.labels_ == label) for label in cluster_ids]

#Data indices belonging to noise group
noise_ixs = np.argwhere(clusterer.labels_ == -1).ravel()

#Data indices belonging to largest group
largest_grp_ixs = np.argwhere(clusterer.labels_ == cluster_ids[np.argmax(membership_counts)]).ravel()


#
# Plotting
#

#Data
plt.scatter(x, y, color='lightgray', s=60, label='data')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(10, 4)

#Noise points
plt.scatter(x[noise_ixs], y[noise_ixs], c='tab:red', s=6, label='noise')

#Largest cluster
plt.scatter(x[largest_grp_ixs], y[largest_grp_ixs], c='tab:green', s=6, label='largest group')

#Formatting
plt.legend()
plt.gca().spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('HDBSCAN on test data')
```


Hi,
thank you very much for your input. i tried your method however maybe I do not understand HDBSCAN correctly, but the results are the same as with DBSCAN or Optics for me. The key is that my constraint is not only density but it also needs to span the entire x axis. HDBSCAN identifies over 30 what clusters and the largest cluster is noise. I tried several hyperparam choices, however I am not an expert on this.

I see. The results you posted seem counter-intuitive to me, as different densities are being flagged as the same cluster. Might be an issue with the code or how the features are handled. Consider including a link to the data if possible.
